# Unity timeline, playing animation clips and controlling playback on events

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if I can get some help on understanding how to use the timeline

I plan to have the character walking along a path with triggers that will activate the timeline,

**I have set up a simple state machine on the monkey**
which would be triggered by the path to play the timeline, that part works fine and I can see the events firing

How could I play part of the timeline when triggered (is that even possible?)
where the entire sequence is held Walk>Jump>Walk>Look>Walk>Idle

Or what would I need to do to be able to achieve playback of a clip/or part of a sequence of clips

**On the monkey:**

```
 public enum State
 {
    WalkHappy,
    Look,
    Jump,
 }

 IEnumerator WalkHappyState()
 {
    Debug.Log("WalkHappy: Enter");
    **//walk sequence with timeline here??**

    while (state == State.WalkHappy)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }
    Debug.Log("WalkHappy: Exit");
    NextState();
}
```

**Called on the paths event listener when triggered**

```
private void OnCustomEvent(string eventname)
{
    if (eventname.Contains("MonkeyRunningJumpUp"))
    {
          GameObject tempMonkey = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
          Monkey tempMonkeyState = tempMonkey.GetComponent<Monkey>();
          tempMonkeyState.state = Monkey.State.Jump;

    }
  }
```

[image]

I have seen its possible to control where the playback starts on a timeline, but I don't know how to force a range/clip to play then pause at the end of the clip rather than the end of the entire sequence

**THE question is.. how to stop/pause at end of a clip to resume later?**

```
   playableDirector = myPlayableDirectorGO.GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
    Debug.Log(timeLinePosition);
    playableDirector.time = timeLinePosition / ((TimelineAsset)playableDirector.playableAsset).editorSettings.fps;
    playableDirector.RebuildGraph();
    playableDirector.Play();
```

with thanks Natalie :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend to install [Default Playables](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/default-playables-95266) if you haven’t done it yet.

Use [Timeline Signals](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2019/05/21/how-to-use-timeline-signals/) and markers to do something at the end of timeline or at certain point. Also, there is [PlayableDirector.stopped](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Playables.PlayableDirector-stopped.html) event.

You can use [pause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Playables.PlayableDirector.Pause.html) and [resume](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Playables.PlayableDirector.Resume.html) methods;